# How do I stop a string of numbers from spontaneously changing?

Tags: python, string

I have a program that uses 0's and 1's to track information, but the problem is that when I store the string 0110000100001000010001110 as a variable, and then immediately print the variable, it has changed into 664085038522079117896, and I have no idea why. The string has to be 25 characters long, and made of 0's and 1's, and this change violates both these rules.

```
pixels = int(input("Enter values: "))
print(pixels)
```

You enter 0110000100001000010001110, then when it prints it has changed to 664085038522079117896.

Comment: I have no idea what you did in the rest of your code, but when i try your code snippet it prints exactly what I typed in.`Enter values: 0110000100001000010001110
110000100001000010001110`

Comment: Is it even necessary to store the binary string? You can achieve the same with an integer and bitwise operations.

Comment: I'd suggest that the answer is stop using Python2 which is out of support

Comment: Make a [mcve] and include the Python version used.

Comment: You're using Python 2, which is past its [end of life](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), meaning it is no longer supported. Unless it's a requirement that you use Python 2, the simplest solution is to use Python 3. Please include any such requirements in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python 2.  `input` evaluates the string and a leading zero indicates an octal number, so `0111` would return the integer 73.  Use `raw_input` to get the string and *don't* convert to `int` if you want to retain your binary string.

In Python 3 this works:

```
>>> pixels = input('Enter values: ')   # use raw_input in Python 2.
Enter values: 01100001
>>> pixels
'01100001'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Now I have only 1500 more lines of code to debug ;)